# Use Next.js Dynamic routing query object in an SWR fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swr

When using Next.js dynamic routing I'm trying to make an SWR fetch request using the routing query object, but my SWR fetch request is being called before the query object is set.

Given the dynamic route `/posts/[id]`, consider the page `/posts/123`.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import useSWR from 'swr';

export default function MyPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;

  const url = `https://my.api.com/posts/${id}`    // I've also tried using let here
  const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher);
  
  console.log(url)
```

This URL initially console logs as `https://my.api.com/posts/undefined` and an error is returned from the API because `https://my.api.com/posts/undefined` is, of course, not a valid path.

Immediately after, the URL console logs correctly as `https://my.api.com/posts/123` and the data on the page usually then populates, but sometimes the data doesn't populate and it's stuck in a 'loading' state. When I hardcode the URL this never happens.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Why is the query object not available immediately? Is there a way to elegantly wait for it to be set?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try to use conditional data fetching like so:

```
const { data, error } = useSWR(id ? url : null, id ? fetcher : null);
```

Also check following conversation: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15952